# Python Requests: downloaded image file binary not identical to original?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am saving image file from the web using Python Requests. However, saved file is a little bit binary different than the original and a bit bigger. It still is a valid jpg file, but scrambled.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import shutil
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

image_url = 'http://www.123.com/image.jpg'
filename = 'out.jpg'
username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypasword'
path = os.path.join('c:/', filename )

r = requests.get(image_url, auth=(username, password), stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = False
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)

print 'The End'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`open(path, 'w')`

should be:

`open(path, 'wb')`

The `b` is for "binary". This will make sure Python won't try to convert character encodings and newlines and reads or writes everything exactly as it is byte-for-byte.

Also see [the `open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open)